# Check if two nodes are on the same path in constant time for a DAG

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, graph-traversal

I have a DAG (directed acyclic graph) which is represented by an edge list e.g.

```
edges = [('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','d')]
```

will give the graph

```
a - > b -> d
|
v
c
```

I'm doing many operations where I have to check if two nodes are on the same path (`b` and `d` are on the same path whereas `b` and `c` are not from example above) which in turn is slowing down my program. I was hoping I could somehow traverse the graph once and save all paths so I can check this in constant time.

Is this speed-up possible and how would I go about to implement this in python?

Edit: 
Note that I need to check for both directions, so if I have a pair of nodes `(a,b)` I need to check for both `a` to `b` and `b` to `a`.

Comment: I don't know which algorithm you are using for this but if you are using an efficient algorithm and still want some improvement in performance, then you might want to convert your processing logic to Cython, maybe you will get some performance gain.

Comment: I'm thinking that traversing the graph is not efficient if I'm going to do that every time I need to check if two nodes are on the same path and I was thinking if it is possible to do this once and then store that information in a dictionary so it can be accessed in constant time later during run-time.

Comment: You want to know if there is path between A and B or B and A ? Being on the same path is vague. What Path? Path from where to where?

Comment: I want to check for both, so if there is a path such that A -> B or B -> A I want to get some type of boolean indicator back.

Comment: what is this 'v' ? isn't it just a---c an edge?

Comment: @SamerTufail it's a downward-pointing arrowhead.

Comment: @AakashM oh completely missed that :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually want to find the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of the graph.

> In computer science, the concept of transitive closure can be thought
>   of as constructing a data structure that makes it possible to answer
>   reachability questions. That is, can one get from node a to node d in
>   one or more hops?

There are multiple ways of finding the transitive closure of the graph. The simplest way is using the [floyd-warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm *O(|V|<sup>3</sup>)*. Explained [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transitive-closure-of-a-graph/).

Another way is to perform a DFS from each node and mark all the nodes you visit as reachable from the current node. Explained [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transitive-closure-of-a-graph-using-dfs/).

There is also a method that works only on DAGs. First perform a topological sorting on your DAG. Then work backward in the topological sorted list and `OR` the transitive closure of the children of the current node together, to get the transitive closure of the current node. Explained [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/efficient-algorithm-for-retrieving-the-transitive-closure-of-a-directed-acyclic).

Below is the Python implementation of the DFS based method:

```
def create_adj_dict_from_edges(edges):
    adj_dict = {}

    for e in edges:
        for u in e:
            if u not in adj_dict:
                adj_dict[u] = []

    for e in edges:
        adj_dict[e[0]].append(e[1])
    return adj_dict

def transitive_closure_from_adj_dict(adj_dict):

    def dfs(node, visited):
        if node not in adj_dict:
            return
        for next in adj_dict[node]:
            if next in visited:
                continue
            visited.add(next)
            dfs(next,visited)

    reachable = {}
    for node in adj_dict:
        visited = set(node,)
        dfs(node,visited)
        reachable[node] = visited

    return reachable

def main():
    edges = [('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','d')]
    adj_dict = create_adj_dict_from_edges(edges)
    tc = transitive_closure_from_adj_dict(adj_dict)
    print tc
    # is there a path from (b to d) or (d to b)
    print 'd' in tc['b'] or 'b' in tc['d']
    # is there a path from (b to c) or (c to b)
    print 'c' in tc['b'] or 'b' in tc['c']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**output**

```
{'a': set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']), 'c': set(['c']), 'b': set(['b', 'd']), 'd': set(['d'])}
True
False
```

Comment: @Chicony the code is updated in order to prevent `key error` for leaf nodes.